# What is the tilde in nginx conf~ files?

Tags: nginx-config

I'm working on a website that uses Nginx to pass requests to a backend http server.  There are two configuration files for the **sites-available** directory.  One is **example.com.conf** and the other is **example.com.conf~**.

Can someone tell me what the **conf~** file is, and secondly, it contains different (incorrect) configuration than those of the **conf** file.

Can I just delete the **conf~** files or are they used for something?  If they are needed, can I just make a copy of the **.conf** to **.conf~**, Thank you!

Comment: Emacs uses ~ to represent backups. Somebody probably edited the configuration file with emacs.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thank you, I will delete all .conf~ files.